# Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined

Tags: json, response, blockchain, rpc

During the install of [this](https://github.com/koneksys/Blockchain4LinkedData) github project I get this error:

```js
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined
at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\backu\blockchain\Blockchain4LinkedData-master\Dapp\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:35:16)
at HttpProvider.send (C:\Users\backu\blockchain\Blockchain4LinkedData-master\Dapp\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:91:22)
at RequestManager.send (C:\Users\backu\blockchain\Blockchain4LinkedData-master\Dapp\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:58:32)
at Eth.send [as getBlock] (C:\Users\backu\blockchain\Blockchain4LinkedData-master\Dapp\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\method.js:145:58)
at Object. (C:\Users\backu\blockchain\Blockchain4LinkedData-master\Dapp\app\routes.js:31:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score -1):

Most likely, when the geth was launched, one of the modules whose methods were used by Dapp was not enabled in the settings of the RPC API. Look at the value of the --rpcapi key from the startup line.